# How to achieve this scala operation in java efficiently

Tags: java, scala, sorting, arraylist

I use `List(1, 2, 3, 4) ::: List(1, 2, 5) distinct` for this issue. It returns `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

How to achieve the same functionality in java and do it very efficiently and elegantly ???

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you can also use Scala library from Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `SortedSet` instead of a `List` to avoid duplicates and have an ordering.
Use

```
set.addAll (otherSet);
```

to add another `Set`.

All in all:

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.addAll (Arrays.asList (1,2,3,4));
set.addAll (Arrays.asList (1,2,5));
```

Well, that's the elegant way. Since you have to use wrapper classes for `int` here, it is maybe not as efficient as you want.

Comment: If the range of integers was within relatively low values, he could even use a `BitSet`

Comment: LinkedHashSet is another alternative.

Comment: There is no easy way in the STL.
Apache Collection provides many useful things for that (it's free, opensource and often used.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html
CollectionUtils.intersection is what your looking for.

Comment: Scala's standard collections also suffer from boxing. But there are alternatives for Scala: https://github.com/non/debox

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly, Scala is internally simply converting this structure into a set in order to provide the `distinct` behavior.  As suggested, using a `TreeSet` or a `LinkedHashSet` (the latter, I suspect, will be faster), will work fine.  Another option, if you're interested in how to efficiently *write* this, is with the fabulous [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

```
List<Integer> distinctLs = new ImmutableSet.Builder<Integer>()
                               .addAll(listOne).addAll(listTwo)
                               .build().asList();
```

In particular, Guava's [immutable collections](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) are able to make many internal optimizations.  For instance their immutable hash collections (`ImmutableSet`, `ImmutableMap`, etc.) preserve insertion order, and the `.asList()` call returns a view in O(1), rather than needing to construct a whole new list in O(n).

---

Guava also lets you construct lists concisely, with `ImmutableList.of(1,2,3,4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 is functional too (somewhat):

```
    IntStream stream1 = IntStream.builder().add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4).build();
    IntStream stream2 = IntStream.builder().add(1).add(2).add(5).build();
    IntStream concatStream = IntStream.concat(stream1, stream2).distinct();
    concatStream.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

I have not used it much; I could not find a simpler way to create an IntStream.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).stream()` works, since if the OP wants a `List`, you'll anyway need to box the `int`s to `Integer`.

Comment: @yshavit No, `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).stream()` gives a `Stream<Integer>`.  I looked around, but I could not find how this can be converted to an `IntStream`.

Comment: Right, but my point is that if the end result that the OP wants is a `List`, then they're going to need a `List<Integer>` -- you can't have a `List<int>`. So in that case, a `Stream<Integer>` works just fine. It has equivalent `concat` and `distinct` methods, too.